# Without using the parameters in URL, what are the ways to access other pages in php

Tags: php

Without passing the parameters in URL, how can we send the variables to other pages and use the functionalities in that pages in php. How can we implement this?

Comment: Redirect page on form action and get data on POST variable

Comment: Sessions and cookies are good too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways to achieve this. 1) using cookie and 2) using session. Using session/cookie you'll have the variable to all the application.

Here're some tutorials for session and cookies.

**Session**

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_2.htm

**Cookie**

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: Any other ways to achieve this type of passing variables. Through classes and functions is it possible?

Comment: @RithuPsks You can also implement your logic using database... but session is good if the data doesn't require permanent storage... what actually you want to achieve? and why can't you use session/cookie?

Comment: I want to use my page variables in a secure manner. Cookies are good idea. Clear cookies may affect the stored variables

Comment: @RithuPsks Then you should go with the database... store your user data in the database in the first page and then retrieve it in the second page and if the data is no longer require remove it from the database...As php is server side scripting language and http protocol doesn't maintain the state so database is the best way to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

There are TWO ways for  send data to other page.
1-  Redirect page on form action and get data on POST variable
2- Set variable data in session and get from session in any other page.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Is it possible in using classes and functions

Comment: YES you can use classes and function for this. but the best way is to set value in session or form posts.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions and Cookies are the best way. Also you can use the classes and functions in php. Other answers are correct